# R, knitr, xtable, using both add.to.row and hline.after

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I’m trying to produce a table with `xtable` in R using `knitr`.  I have inserted a header and extra `\hline`s.
I’m using the `add.to.row` command to insert my header at the top, as well as midway through the table.
I can’t seem to get the `hline.after` command correct.

I would like my table to look like two tables (though it's one), with an hline after the 4th row of numbers and before the second heading.
After using the `add.to.row` command, I can’t seem to put lines there.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

<<table, results='asis'>>=
require(knitr)
require(xtable)    

# Generate some data
set.seed(1683)
dat <- rnorm(48)
tab <- as.data.frame(matrix(dat, nrow=6, ncol=8))

addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list()
addtorow$pos[[1]] <- 0
addtorow$pos[[2]] <- 0
addtorow$pos[[3]] <- 4
addtorow$pos[[4]] <- 4
addtorow$command <- c(' & & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 1} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 2} & 
                     \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 3}  \\\\\n',  
                   " name & $\\hat{\\beta}$ & A & B & A & B & A & B  \\\\\n", 
                   " & & & & & & & \\\\\n",
                   " name & $\\hat{\\sigma}$ & A & B & A & B & A & B  \\\\\n")


print(xtable(tab, align="rrccccccc"), add.to.row=addtorow, ,     include.rownames=FALSE, 
  include.colnames=FALSE, hline.after = c(-1, 0, 4, nrow(tab)))
@


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the lines inside the `add.to.row`

```
addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list()
addtorow$pos[[1]] <- 0
addtorow$pos[[2]] <- 0
addtorow$pos[[3]] <- 4
addtorow$pos[[4]] <- 4
addtorow$pos[[5]] <- 4
addtorow$pos[[6]] <- 4
addtorow$command <- c(' & & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 1} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 2} & 
                     \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 3}  \\\\\n',  
                   " name & $\\hat{\\beta}$ & A & B & A & B & A & B  \\\\\n", 
                   " \\hline\n",
                   " & & & & & & & \\\\\n",
                   " \\hline\n",
                   " name & $\\hat{\\sigma}$ & A & B & A & B & A & B  \\\\\n")

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccccccc}
  \hline
   & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 2} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 3}  \\
  name & $\hat{\beta}$ & A & B & A & B & A & B  \\
  \hline
   1.28 & -0.71 & 1.30 & -1.08 & -0.32 & -0.84 & -0.75 & 0.67 \\ 
  -0.83 & -0.41 & 0.09 & 0.29 & -0.91 & -0.04 & -1.61 & -0.71 \\ 
  -1.82 & 0.16 & -0.34 & 0.39 & -1.58 & 0.44 & -0.81 & -0.89 \\ 
  -2.03 & 0.30 & 1.27 & -0.46 & -1.02 & 2.98 & -0.34 & -0.75 \\ 
  \hline
  & & & & & & & \\
  \hline
  name & $\hat{\sigma}$ & A & B & A & B & A & B  \\
 \hline
0.88 & 1.44 & 0.11 & -0.66 & -2.31 & -1.21 & -0.06 & 0.22 \\ 
  0.43 & 1.07 & -1.10 & 0.93 & -0.72 & 1.52 & -1.52 & -0.83 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```